# Keep SQL Connection Alive during ReadItem

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, bcs

Is there any way to keep a connection open during the ReadItem process or is there a best practice around this?

Basically if i'm calling ReadItem in BCS 100K times, how can I streamline that connection if I have to read from SQL.

Update/More Info: We have a database with around 2-20 million rows, so if I make a connection through FAST/Search 2013, the ReadList can be large, so I'm looking to speed up the process of reading each one via ReadItem. This is a pretty standard FAST Search/BCS setup connecting to a current SQL DB. Nothing very fancy, but the volume of data becomes an issue, so tuning is important.

Comment: I think first you need to provide more information. Like pasting your code, describing your business process why you are doing ReadItem 100K times instead of doing batches and so on.

Comment: Use ReadList with filters instead. No way you can achieve what you want with ReadItem.